# if the "android update project" command can be replace by java code?

Tags: java, android, ant

I'm using ant to build Android project, it needs execute the command "android update project"。Now， it is "`Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd)`".

I want to know if there is any other way can do that, but faster than Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd).

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this code: String[] cmd = { "android update project -p " + fullPath + "/app/src/main -t android-22" };
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); and always getting error=2, No such file or directory, same string working in terminal. Any ideas? Tnx